# How to test for non-numeric input data?

Tags: excel, vba, numeric

I am developing a program in Excel 2016 VBA.

I am trying to check for non-numeric data selected by the user.

I have the following example data:

[image]

My code takes the selection specified by the user and stores it in a 2D array named X1. I then loop through both dimensions and test whether each cell is numeric using:

```
If Not IsNumeric(X1(i, j)) Then
```

If true, then it is supposed to go to error handling. My code
correctly identifies the orange highlighted cell and sends it to error handling, however, my code does not catch the yellow highlighted cell.

I know that the ampersand sign is a the concatenate operator. I assume this is part of the problem.

Comment: Try `IF not Application.IsNumber(X1(i, j)) Then`

Comment: VBA seems to interpret `&6` as `"" & "6"` which is `"6"`, hence numeric.

Comment: or you can do `If iserror(evaluate("--" & selection)) then`

Comment: Thank you both!! John: That makes a lot of sense now, thank you for the insight.

Comment: Scott: I added your code as a new condition to the statement and it works great!!

Comment: If Not IsNumeric(X1(i, j)) Or IsError(Evaluate("--" & X1(i, j))) Then

Comment: Along similar lines, what if instead of a cell with &6 the user selects a range with a cell with only a & and I want to search for these and convert them to something else. The usual REPLACE() fn does not seem to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

VBA Excel 2010 help
 IsNumeric returns True if the entire expression is recognized as a number; otherwise, it returns False.
 IsNumeric returns False if expression is a date expression.

numeric data type
Any intrinsic numeric data type (Byte, Boolean, Integer, Long, Currency, Single, Double, or Date).

numeric expression
Any expression that can be evaluated as a number. Elements of an expression can include any combination of keywords, variables, constants, and operators that result in a number.

numeric type
Any intrinsic numeric data type (Byte, Boolean, Integer, Long, Currency, Single, Double, or Date) or any Variant numeric subtype (Empty, Integer, Long, Single, Double, Currency, Decimal, Date, Error, Boolean, or Byte).

An ordinary person needs another isnumeric - Real

```
Public Function Is_Numeric_Real( _
       ByVal v As Variant) _
       As Boolean

    Dim decSep As String
    decSep = Application.DecimalSeparator

    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    bReturn = True

    Dim str As String
    str = CStr(v)

    Dim symb As String
    Dim x As Long

    For x = 1 To Len(str)

        symb = Mid$(str, x, 1)

        If is_Number(symb) = False And _
           symb <> decSep Then

            bReturn = False

            Exit For

        End If
    Next x

    Is_Numeric_Real = bReturn

End Function

Public Function is_Number( _
       ByVal v As Variant) _
       As Boolean
' Тестом покрыто
' цифра ли
    If Asc(v) > 47 Then
        If Asc(v) < 58 Then
            is_Number = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```